# How to compute complexity of these nested loops?

Tags: loops, complexity-theory

```
while(n > 0){    
    while(n > 0){   
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            cout << ":) ";
            m--;
        }
        n--;
    }
    n--;
}
```

How to compute complexity? `n` is any natural number.

---

OK, I'm correcting my code:

```
while(n > 0){    
    while(s > 0){   
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            cout << ":) ";
            m--;
        }
        s--;
    }
    n--;
}
```

Now, how to compute complexity of that?

Answer (score 2):

The outer while loop is only run once since when the inner while loop is complete n equals 0 and the outer loop is no longer run through.

Therefore the complexity will still be O(n*m)

**EDIT**: Just in case you meant to use a different loop variable (say k) in the outer loop, the complexity would be O(k*n*m)

Answer (score 1):

A formal manner to compute your nested loops complexity (based on your corrected code):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
O(n*m)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
while(n>0)
{
   for(int i=0; i < m; i++)
   {
   }
n--;
}
```

Because as pointed out, the terminating condition for both the `while` loops is the same, when the inner one terminates, the outer `while` loop terminates too.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider that you meant three different variables.

The first while(n > 0) loop runs for exactly n steps,

The second while(n > 0) loop again runs for exactly n steps,

The for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) loop runs for M/2 steps since at each step, i is incremented and m is decremented making the for loop equivalent to

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i+=2){
            cout << ":) ";
        }
```

So the time complexity is O(N*N*M/2) = O(N^2*M)

If the while loops are meant to be same, then the outer loop is just a duplicate and would do nothing.

So the time complexity in this case is O(N*M/2) = O(N*M)